# Integration height after area of curve

Tags: integration

I'm looking at getting the area under curves with integration. I'm fine getting the area, but once you find the area I'm wondering how you would go by getting the height of the curve.

Edit: My function is $$f(x) = 6-x-x^2, \;\;\text{ between }\;x = -3\text{ and } \;x = 2.$$

I found the area to be $\dfrac{125}{6}$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any particular example you would like to share with the community?

Comment: My function is f(x) = 6-x-x^2 between. X = -3 and x = 2. I found the area to be 125/6

Comment: What is the height of a curve?

Comment: 1/ square root of 2πσ

Comment: Where do you draw this formula from ???

Comment: For the height? I've just looked throughout Google as I'm teaching myself

Comment: @ShaunaGoodmanFitzpatrick Take note of the given answer and accept if it clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \text{Average Height} = \dfrac{\text{Area}}{\text{base}}$$

$$ =   \dfrac{\int_{-3}^{+2}(6-x-x^2)dx}{base= 2-(-3)}$$

$$ \dfrac{125/6}{5}$$

$$ \text{Height} =\frac{25}{6}$$
etc.

Comment: @Babak. S Thanks.. ( Was just trying Latex $ \text{Average Height  = Area/base }$ ). Not really to change it,

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the area between between the $x$-axis, and your function $f(x) = 6-x-x^2$.

What you have is a ***parabola*** that opens downward (because of the negative coefficient of the term $x^2$: $$f(x) = 6-x-x^2 = -(x^2 + x-6) = -(x+3)(x-2).$$

Note that the downward-opening parabola intersects the $x$-axis where $$f(x) = -(x+3)(x-2)= 0,$$

which happens at $x=-3$ and at $x=2$, precisely the endpoints of the interval in question.

Because the parabola is symmetric about the midpoint of the interval $(-3, 2),$ the vertex of the parabola will be when $$x= \frac{-3 + 2}2 = -0.5,$$

Substitute $x=-0.5$ into $f(x)$ to see that the vertex is at  $(-0.5, f(-0.5)),$ where $\;f(-0.5) = \dfrac {25}{4}$  (it's height as measured from the point $(x, 0) =(-0.5, 0))$

[image]

[image]

We can also differentiate to find $f'(x)$ and then solve $f'(x) = 0$. If you do this, you'll find the same result: $$f'(x) = -2x-1 = 0 \iff x = -0.5.$$ 
You can check to show that at $x=-0.5$, $f(x)$ attains its maximum. Then as described above: To find the maximum height of the parabola as measured on over the interval $x\in (-3, 2)$, we have $$f(-0.5)= \frac{25}4 = 6.25$$